# How to implement the Countable interface in PHP?

Tags: php, class, interface, count

So that `count($object)` will return the number of records in it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [Countable::count](http://php.net/manual/en/countable.count.php)

```
class MyClass implements Countable {
    public function count() {
        //return count
    }
}

$c = new MyClass();
count($c); //calls $c->count();
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have Standard PHP Library installed you should be able to simply implement Countable in your class and then define the count() function:

```
class foo implements Countable {
    ...
    public function count() {
        # do stuff here
        return $count;
    }
}
```

Read more about the SPL here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php

More about the Countable interface here:
http://php.net/manual/en/countable.count.php

Answer (score 3):

Note that if your class is **namespaced**, you have to give the Countable interface the root namespace:

```php
namespace App;

class MyClass implements Countable {
    public function count() {
    //return count
    }
}
```

The above throws an error:

> Interface 'App\Countable' not found

To solve (note the slash in front of Countable):

```php
namespace App;

class MyClass implements \Countable {
    public function count() {
    //return count
    }
}
```

(FYI, not sure if this is particular to Laravel but I assume not.)